# Examples of simultaneous independent breakthroughs

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list

I'm looking for examples where, after a long time with little progress, a simultaneous mathematical discovery, solution, or breakthrough was made independently by at least two different people/groups. Two examples come to mind:

1. [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). This was proved by Jacques Hadamard and Charles Jean de la Vallée Poussin in 1896.
2. Sum of three fourth powers equals a fourth power. In 1986, [Noam Elkies](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2008781) proved that there are infinitely many integer solutions to $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = d^4$. His smallest example was $2682440^4 + 15365639^4 + 18796760^4 = 20615673^4$. [Don Zagier](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.243) reported that he found a solution independently just weeks later.

Can you give other instances?

Comment: This happens frequently. Search for the word "independently" in abstracts or in the conclusion (or introduction) of papers.  My name appears in Algebra Universalis because Libor Polak acknowledged my near simultaneous solution to a problem in logic he solved.  (In this case though, the problem had not been around long.) Gerhard "Or Look Up 'On Hyperassociativity'" Paseman, 2019.07.26.

Comment: Having studied [the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509526/more-elliptic-curves-for-x4y4z4-1) $a^4+b^4+c^4 = 1$ and [the case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191316/more-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4d4-abcd4) $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$, the Zagier anecdote was interesting to know.

Comment: There was some discussion of *why* there are simultaneous independent discoveries at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709969/why-are-mathematical-results-discovered-by-multiple-people-independently

Answer (score 58):

One of the most entertaining seminar talks I ever attended was by Michael Atiyah on the moment map on a Lie group. As the talk progressed, the people in the front row became more and more agitated, until Raoul Bott finally spoke up, said something like, "Michael, these guys just proved the same theorem last week!", and pointed to Victor Guillemin and Shlomo Sternberg.

Comment: What a moment-ous occasion.

Comment: There is an expository article on the theorem at http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~apires/convexitytalk.pdf

Comment: @MattF, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

The [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a\ne0,1$, and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number, was proved independently in 1934 by Aleksandr Gelfond and Theodor Schneider.

Answer (score 21):

One of the most famous ones seems to be Newton vs. Leibniz, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319725611

Comment: Neither was solving a problem, however. Arguably what both were doing was to turn various ideas that had been around for a while into a “method”. A breakthrough nonetheless, I suppose.

Comment: The common story is that devising calculus was a gradual process for both of them (not surprising) with enough communication between them that each could accuse the other of stealing the idea(s).

Answer (score 20):

The solution of [Hilbert's  nineteenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_nineteenth_problem), in 1957, by Ennio De Giorgi and John Nash, few months later.

Answer (score 18):

The near simultaneous solution to Serre's conjecture on projective modules over polynomial rings by Quillen and Suslin independently comes to mind.

Answer (score 13):

Recent example in analytic number theory:

http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2016/183-3/p03

and

http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2016/183-3/p04

Comment: Please give more than just two links.

Comment: From a non-expert point of view, it seems that this was already a hot topic with lots of activity, so it would not qualify for "after a long time with little progress". Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn the specific problem they solved have remain virtually untouched since the 1960s. What Erdos proposed was very modest: can one prove that there exist infinitely may primes $p$ such that the gap between $p$ and the next prime $p^\prime$ is at least $c \cdot g(p)$, where $g$ is a very specific function and $c$ an arbitrarily large positive number. Both sets of authors accomplished this and released their results within a week of each other.

Comment: It's true that these two papers were independent of each other, but they both relied heavily on Yitang Zhang's breakthrough, which had happened not long before. Somehow this makes the papers seem less independent than some of the other examples in this list.

Comment: @TimothyChow I am not sure I agree with your assertion that both of the papers fundamentally depend on Yitang Zhang's breakthrough. In fact, I think this statement applies to neither paper. If one has to argue that both papers rely on an earlier but recent progress, it should be the Maynard-Tao sieve which was discovered not long after Zhang's seminal result, but essentially independent of it.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao : Perhaps I am misinformed, but are you saying that these papers would have appeared anyway even if Zhang had never published his result? My impression was that some of the basic ideas were inspired by Zhang's breakthrough even though the final proofs do not logically rely on it.

Comment: @TimothyChow the story is a bit convoluted. When Maynard announced his proof of bounded gaps between primes, there was much speculation as to whether or not he already had the key ideas before Zhang surprisingly announced his proof six months prior. I talked to James directly and he confirmed to me that he did not, as of May 2013, believed he had a proof of the result, but was inspired by Zhang's work to refine an earlier method of his which ultimately turned into a proof of bounded gaps. Tao gave a similar idea on his blog around the same time as Maynard's paper appeared on arxiv.

Comment: One can look at Maynard's earlier work, which is now published as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X15000657, and confirm that he has essentially developed his sieve independently of Zhang's work. This is also clear if one is familiar with how Zhang and Maynard's proofs work... they are quite different. Zhang's key idea was that a restricted improvement to the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem, which gives a slightly larger level of distribution, could be proved and combined with the earlier work of Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim, would give bounded gaps.

Comment: ... continued: Whereas Maynard's argument is based on an entirely different sieve, based on a more elementary construction due to Selberg. In particular, Maynard's argument is more robust and powerful in the sense that it only requires ANY positive level of distribution to yield bounded gaps, whereas Zhang's argument fundamentally depends on the level of distribution being larger than $1/2$. Further, Maynard's sieve gives that for any $k \geq 2$ there are infinitely many $k$-tuples of primes within a bounded gap $C(k)$, whereas Zhang's argument only works for $k = 2$.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao : Very interesting! Now I am curious about how Tao came to a similar idea. Was Tao inspired by Zhang's work?

Answer (score 13):

A very recent example appears to be the simultaneous discovery of functorial (and "easy") resolution of singularities in characteristic 0 by McQuillan-Marzo (arXiv:1906.06745) respectively Abramovich-Temkin-Włodarczyk (arXiv:1906.07106).

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if it satisfies the criteria of "a long time with little progress", but one example of a simultaneous mathematical discovery is the discovery of the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). Here is how Bruce Sagan describes it in his book *The Symmetric Group*:

> One Thursday in May of 1953, Robinson was visiting Frame at Michigan State University. Discussing the work of Staal (a student of Robinson), Frame was led to conjecture the hook formula. At first Robinson could not believe that such a simple formula existed, but after trying some examples he became convinced, and together they proved the identity. On Saturday they went to the University of Michigan, where Frame presented their new result after a lecture by Robinson. This surprised Thrall, who was in the audience, because he had just proved the same result on the same day!

Answer (score 11):

Abel and Galois were working independently and did not know each other. Their approaches were different but they solved (among other things) an old and famous problem.

There are many other examples: Abel and Jacobi (elliptic functions),
Bolyai, Lobachevski and Gauss independently developed non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Will it be correct to say that Abel and Galois solved the same problem?

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: Yes, besides other things they proved unsolvability of a general equation of degree >4 in radicals.

Comment: I thought it was Abel who proved this... Didn't Galois know this?

Comment: Galois was aware of Abel's work: https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF00357046

Comment: Galois knew Abel’s work and solved a different problem as well. Plus, there is a distance of about 10 years.

Answer (score 11):

Richard Friedberg and Albert Muchnik independently and almost simultaneously solved [Post's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree#Post%27s_problem_and_the_priority_method).

Answer (score 11):

A conjecture from the 1950s (arising from a result of Kaplansky) was that for any compact Hausdorff space $X$,  every algebra homomorphism from $C(X)$ into another Banach algebra is automatically continuous. This conjecture was refuted in the late 1970s, independently, by H. Garth Dales and Jean Esterle: a very short announcement which outlines some of the ideas can be found in

H. G. Dales and J. Esterle, *Discontinuous homomorphisms from C(X).*
 [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 83 (1977), 257–259](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1977-83-02/S0002-9904-1977-14291-2/home.html)

Both approaches assumed the continuum hypothesis; later work of Solovay exhibited models of ZFC in which the original conjecture has a positive answer.

Answer (score 10):

Van der Waerden's conjecture on the permanent of a doubly stochastic matrix had been open for 50 years when it was proved independently by Falikman and Egorychev.

Answer (score 10):

[Ramanujan graphs](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/new-ramanujan-graphs/) were independently constructed by Margulis and by Lubotzky–Phillips–Sarnak.

Answer (score 10):

The theoretical basis of Linear Optimization has been independently developed in the time of the second world war by L.V. Kantorovich and by G.B. Dantzig.

Answer (score 8):

The independence of the [Parallel Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) had been open for about 2000 years when its independence had been independently by Bolyai, Lobachevski and Gauss around 1830; Gauss never published his proof, but only claimed to have solved the problem when he was informed about Bolyai's proof.

Comment: That said, there is no doubt that Gauss was very much occupied with this question since the time he was a young teenager, and he spoke in some detail about his ideas regarding this question in letters to others. So I think it's a case of more than "only claiming".

Comment: @ToddTrimble I was only being careful with my formulation, taking the point of view of [Janos Bolyai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1nos_Bolyai) at that time; Janos Bolyai had suspected that Gauss had 'stolen' his ideas which he assumed his father Farkas had mentioned in letters to Gauss . The English wikipedia article doesn't mention that, whereas the [German wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1nos_Bolyai) mentions that Janos developed a serious illness after Gauss said to already have made the discovery. I also think that Gauss was everything else but dishonest.

Comment: Gauss, true to form, did not behave all that graciously with regard to Bolyai, saying in a letter to Farkas Bolyai (formerly a schoolmate of Gauss), in effect, "I cannot bring myself to praise this accomplishment of your son Janos, because to do so would be praising myself". He ends that letter on a slightly better note, but there is no doubt that the letter was received as a wet blanket on the young man's enthusiasm. But "stealing" is wrong: Gauss had already worked out detailed calculations on hyperbolic geometry and had satisfied himself that it was wholly consistent.

Comment: I cannot make out what you are alleging in your final sentence, "I also think that Gauss was everything else but dishonest."

Comment: @ToddTrimble I'm not a native Engllish speaker; what I wanted to say is that I believe that Gauss was a man of honor and didn't claim anything that wasn't true.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I thought the independence of the Parallel Postulate (i.e. the consistency of hyperbolic geometry) was proved by Beltrami in 1868?

Comment: @bof you are right, but lets say the discovery of non-euclidean geometries, where the parallel postulate doesn't hold, took place almost simultaneously by three persons.The difference between finding examples, where the parallel postulate is violated and proving the independence of the parallel postulate isn't always made explicit.

Answer (score 7):

The theory of [NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem#Contributions) was simultaneously and independently developed in North America and the U.S.S.R.

Comment: Was Cook still in the U.S. when he proved NP-completeness of SAT?

Comment: I quote the following from an article by Richard Karp: "Steve Cook was primarily in math but also in the new CS Department. It is to our everlasting shame that we were unable to persuade the math department to give him tenure. Perhaps they would have done so if he had published his proof of the np-completeness of satisfiability a little earlier." (from https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/bears/CS_Anniversary/karp-talk.html )

This would seem to indicate that Cook didn't publish the NP-completeness of SAT until he was in Toronto.

Comment: The paper itself also associates Cook with the University of Toronto. (https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/1971.pdf)

Comment: OK but the answer claims he developed it in the US and makes no claims about where he was by the time it was published.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's why I asked about "when he proved" rather than "when he published".

Answer (score 7):

Recently I reviewed

Shmerkin, Pablo On Furstenberg's intersection conjecture, self-similar measures, and the $L^q$ norms of convolutions. Ann. of Math. (2) 189 (2019), 2, 319--391

and obverved that another proof of Furstenberg's intersection conjecture is given in

Wu, Meng, A proof of Furstenberg’s conjecture on the intersections of ×p and ×q-invariant sets, Ann. of Math. (2) 189, 3, 707-751, (2019)

The methods of the proofs seems to be quite different.

Answer (score 6):

The "class number one" problem for imaginary quadratic fields was posed by Gauss in 1798, settled independently by Baker and Stark in 1966/7. Gauss had found nine imaginary quadratic fields with class number one (which, in this context, is equivalent to unique factorization into primes) and conjectured there were no others; Baker and Stark proved this.

(There was also a proof by Heegner some years earlier than the work of Baker and Stark, but this proof had some minor gaps and was not generally accepted until Stark showed how to fill the gaps in 1969.)

Answer (score 6):

The equivalence of [nondeterministic logarithmic complexity class (NL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_(complexity)) to the class whose complements are in NL (co-NL) was proven independently by [Neil Immerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Immerman) (University of Massachusetts, Amherst, MA, USA) and [Róbert Szelepcsényi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B3bert_Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi) (Comenius University, Bratislava, Slovakia).  This result is known as the [Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem) and they shared the 1995 Gödel Prize for it.

Answer (score 5):

During the summer of 2001, Crew's conjecture in the theory of $p$-adic differential equations was simultaneously proved in three very different ways by André, Kedlaya, and Mebkhout.

Answer (score 5):

The word problem for groups was shown to be undecidable by Pyortr Novikov in 1955 and William Boone in 1958. Since there was practically no academic communication between their home countries (USSR and USA, respectively) at the time, the consensus is that the discoveries were independent.

Comment: Independent, yes, but does it qualify as "simultaneous", as requested by OP?

Answer (score 4):

In 1992, Feder and Vardi conjectured that for every constraint language $\Gamma$, the constraint satisfaction problem with constraints from $\Gamma$ is either solvable in polynomial time or is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete.  Progress was made on special cases and related problems but not a whole lot happened until [Bulatov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03021) and [Zhuk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01914) independently announced proofs of the conjecture in March and April 2017.

As I recall, a third proof was announced at around the same time, but was subsequently found to be erroneous and withdrawn.

Answer (score 4):

The [HOMFLY or HOMFLYPT polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOMFLY_polynomial) is a clear example. The polynomial was introduced in "A new polynomial invariant of knots and links", and on the first page there is a footnote:

> Editor's Note. The editors received, virtually within a period of a few days in late September and early October 1984, four research announcements, each describing the same result—the existence and properties of a new polynomial invariant for knots and links. There was variation in the approaches taken by the four groups and variation in corollaries and elaboration. These were: *A new invariant for knots and links* by Peter Freyd and David Yetter; *A polynomial invariant of knots and links* by Jim Hoste; *Topological invariants of knots and links*, by W. B. R. Lickorish and Kenneth C. Millett, and *A polynomial invariant for knots: A combinatorial and an algebraic approach*, by A. Ocneanu.
>
> It was evident from the circumstances that the four groups arrived at their results completely independently of each other, although all were inspired by the work of Jones (cf. [10], and also [8, 9]). The degree of simultaneity was such that, by common consent, it was unproductive to try to assess priority. Indeed it would seem that there is enough credit for all to share in.
>
> Each of these papers was refereed, and we would have happily published any one of them, had it been the only one under consideration. Because the alternatives of publication of all four or of none were both unsatisfying, all have agreed to the compromise embodied here of a paper carrying all six names as coauthors, consisting of an introductory section describing the basics written by a disinterested party, and followed by four sections, one written by each of the four groups, briefly describing the highlights of their own approach and elaboration.

The result also appears in work by Józef H. Przytycki and Paweł Traczyk, hence the PT.
The reason for simultaneous discovery is quite clear: the HOMFLYPT polynomial is a relatively straightforward generalization of the (at the time) recently introduced Jones polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the most famous example would be Newton-Leibniz development of Calculus, but there is also the case of Lagrange and Euler when developing the calculus of variations. A list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_discoveries).

Comment: I think Lagrange knew Euler’s work.

Comment: Newton-Leibniz was mentioned by another user a couple of days earlier than this post.

Answer (score 2):

The [angel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem) was posed in 1982, and little progress was made until it was solved independently and almost simultaneously in 2006 by four different people. To borrow from the Wikipedia article, the question is to determine the winner of a certain game:

> The game is played by two players called the angel and the devil. It is played on an infinite chessboard. The angel has a power $k \in \mathbb{N}$ specified before the game starts. On each turn, the angel flies to a different square whose distance from its current square is at most $k$ in the infinity norm. The devil, on its turn, may permanently block any single square not containing the angel. The angel may fly over blocked squares, but cannot land on them. The devil wins if the angel is unable to move. The angel wins by surviving indefinitely.

The problem was first published in the book *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays* by Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy and therefore became fairly well known among people interested in recreational mathematics. However, arguably the reason for the sudden appearance of four independent solutions in 2006 was the publication of Peter Winkler's book *Mathematical Puzzles: A Connoisseur's Collection*, which listed the angel problem as an unsolved problem, and presumably sparked the interest of a lot of people who had either not heard the problem before, or at least had not given it much thought.

Answer (score 2):

The [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) was a challenge posed by David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann in 1928. The problem asks for an algorithm that considers, as input, a statement and answers "Yes" or "No" according to whether the statement is universally valid, i.e., valid in every structure satisfying the axioms.

The problem was solved independently by [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) and [A. M. Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) in 1936. Church's solution was based on lambda calculus, whereas Turing's approach was based on hypothetical computational devices now known as Turing Machines.

On a related note, a definition of computation was also provided independently by [Emil L. Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Leon_Post) in 1936, and is equivalent to the the other two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Hillel Furstenberg and Robert Zimmer simultaneously proved a powerful structure theorem for measure preserving dynamical systems: [exposition at Tao’s blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/254a-lecture-15-the-furstenberg-zimmer-structure-theorem-and-the-furstenberg-recurrence-theorem/).  Furstenberg’s article also contains a proof of a [conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%E2%80%93S%C3%A1rk%C3%B6zy_theorem) of László Lovász, on the density of a set of integers, no two of which differ by a perfect square.  This was proved simultaneously and independently with a different method, by András Sárközy.

Answer (score 0):

Ray and Singer conjectured that their analytic torsion should carry the same information as Reidemeister torsion. This was then proved independently by Cheeger and Müller, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_torsion).

But maybe this does not count because the phase of inactivity was not that long ...

Comment: I think the setting for Cheeger and Muller's proof is slightly different. Cheeger's proof made some hypothesis which is not in original Ray-Singer paper. But this is based on my memory; I have not checked the paper for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

A [completely new algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) for calculating $\pi$ was independently discovered by Salamin and Brent in 1976. This iterative algorithm, which doubles the number of correct digits with each iteration, is based on work of Gauss (arithmetic-geometric means) that had been neglected for 170 years.

Comment: I quite disagree with the "neglected for 170 years"characterization; people have used AGM to compute elliptic integrals and functions way before the Brent-Salamin proposal (e.g. [King](https://archive.org/details/onthenumerical032686mbp) (1924), [Bartky](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.10.264) (1938), [Salzer](https://doi.org/10.1145/368273.368573) (1962), [Bulirsch](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01397975) (1965)). Relatedly, the Legendre relation on which Brent-Salamin is built on was presented in the 1800s, around the same time Gauss started investigating the AGM.

Comment: This answer would better suit https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176425/rediscovery-of-lost-mathematics

Answer (score 0):

Last month (September 2020) Chodosh and Li uploaded a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.11888.pdf) showing that a closed aspherical manifold of dimension $4$ or $5$ does not admit a Riemannian metric with positive scalar curvature.

On exactly the same day Gromov uploaded a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.05332.pdf) which used similar ideas to generalize the result of Chodosh and Li to higher dimension (again, as usual, the fact that they were both submitted on the same day was almost certainly coordinated between the authors and not a coincidence).